# Horizontally repositioning a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Is it possible to reposition a `UIBarButtonItem` that's in a `UINavigationBar` horizontally? I've seen the `barButtonItem setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:` method (but that's for vertical positioning), and I know how to do it if I make it a custom button, but how do I take a `UIBarButtonItem` with the style `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` and horizontally reposition it (that is, move it left or right)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a fixed size button as a 'filler' and add that to beside your existing button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
```

(Then set the width to your desired value)

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how do I do this with a ```UINavigationBar```? I'm making the ```UIBarButtonItem``` the ```UINavigationItem```'s ```leftBarButtonItem```, so how do I add a fixed space?

Comment: You need to use `leftBarButtonItems` (note the multiplicity, you pass an array of button items).

Comment: Great, it works! Just a note for anyone else who comes across this answer -- the fixed space should always be the first in the array of ```UIBarButtonItems``` (regardless of which side it's supposed to be on).

Comment: That depends on if it's the left or right button items you set. Check the docs, the order is specified.